# Ansible: validating a variable inside a multi-dimensional array/dict in one statement

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible

With the `uri` module (though this issue isn't limited to that) you can query a web endpoint and get a result back, and I'm trying to validate (with a `when` conditional) an object in the JSON response.  Unfortunately the actual value is (roughly) in:

```
registered_variable_name.json.result.my_key
```

The issue is to test `my_key` it seems like I need to first verify:

1. is `registered_variable_name` defined?
2. is `registered_variable_name.json` defined?
3. is `registered_variable_name.json.result` defined?

then

4. is `registered_variable_name.json.result.my_key`'s value what I want?

That seems over-complicated so I'm hoping there is an easier way of just testing `my_key`'s value, because if any level of that `dict` is missing it seems to either throw an error or just not validate correctly (e.g. there is no JSON response due to an error, or the there is a JSON response but no `result` element, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine (with ansible 2.1.1.0):

- debug:
  msg: "The key is defined"
  when: registered_variable_name.json.result.my_key is defined
      and registered_variable_name.json.result.my_key == 'target value'

Here's a complete example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  name: Key exists and matches
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    varname:
      json:
        result:
          my_key: target value

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "The key exists."
      when: varname.json.result.my_key is defined
            and varname.json.result.my_key == "target value"

- hosts: localhost
  name: Key exists but no match
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    varname:
      json:
        result:
          my_key: "these are not the droids you're looking for"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "The key exists."
      when: varname.json.result.my_key is defined
            and varname.json.result.my_key == "target value"

- hosts: localhost
  name: Key does not exist
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    varname: nothing to see here

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "The key exists."
      when: varname.json.result.my_key is defined
            and varname.json.result.my_key == "target value"
```